# Convert string to base32 in PHP

Tags: php, string, encode

I have to pass username as an unique string to a webservice, and the API is asking for the following.

1. Unique string has to be converted to BASE16
2. It is the BASE16 value I have to pass.

I cannot find a way to convert the value to BASE16.
PHP does not seem to have a `BASE16_ENCODE` like it does for BASE64.

Example:

```
$value = <username as an unique string>;
$base16username = base16_encode('$value'); (< Since Base16_encode does not exist, this is my problem)
```

Google searches are leading me nowhere, nor is the PHP online manual so I suspect I might be overlooking something obvious. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: Base16 is hexadecimal (PHP has bin2hex)

Comment: Or you check how a base64 encoding actually works and then you adapt it to your needs. That is no rocket science...

Comment: Are you looking for base16 or 32? Your question body and title is misleading

Comment: Accept the answer if it solved your problem. Respect other people in this community!

Answer (score 3):

- Go to [packagist.org](http://packagist.org)
- search: base32
- find [christian-riesen/base32](https://packagist.org/packages/christian-riesen/base32)

Include the package in your `composer.json` and use it like so:

```
$encoded = Base32::encode($string);
```

Comment: @VargheseAkhil If it works for you, it's better to accept the answer and upvote instead of commenting :)